# Database design: should I use separate tables or merge them in this example?

Tags: database, database-design

Suppose we have a Question entity and an Answer entity and each Question can have no more than one Answer. Of course, a Question can have no Answer or could be answered later, but a Question is corresponding to no more than one Answer.

From one point of view, I can create a table Question with all the necessary information about the Question and the Answer entities. I think this seems relevant.

From another point of view, the miniworld may require that every user can like/upvote both the Question and the Answer.

This can be achieved almost the same in both cases, with the following two tables, indicating a relation:

1. UserUpvotesQuestion (storing the id of the User and the id of the Question)
2. UserUpvotesAnswer (storing the id of the User and again the id of the Question)

Both tables would have the same schema but different meaning. However, isn't this becoming very ugly and confusing? What if I just separate the two entities in two tables - Question and Answer and then have the UserUpvotesQuestion and UserUpovtesAnswer tables created respectively.

Although having a 1:1 relationship, I consider the second way a better approach but I'm not sure I'm right.

Comment: it feels like you are missing the user part - does the same question really only get answered once? or once per user?

Comment: This was just an example, which is equivalent to my case. I decided to give this example because it is easier to explain than the situation with my case. So, yes, a question should have only one answer (not one per user).

Comment: one to ones are a little tricky - maybe ask yourself this: does one ever exist and interact in the world without the other? if so - then make a separate table - if not then all in one.

Comment: This sounds relevant. In my case the relationship is one to one, but an Answer can be answered (created), edited, deleted, being voted for, reported separetely from the Question. So, I think separate tables may be a better approach.