# Have a table for every basic types or merge them into one table

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design

I have over 100 basic types in my project. Assume that all of them just contains an Id and a Title , so which of these approach is better to use :

**Approach 1** : create a separate table for each of them

**Approach 2** : Create a table for all of them and use another field as discriminator

I am using Using `MSSQL` server with `Entity Framework Code-First Approach` . Actually I can not decide which approach I should choose to use.

I think the question is self-briefed , but Let me know if you need more details.

**UPDATE1** : Please do not refer me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489544/database-design-should-i-use-separate-tables-or-merge-them-in-this-example) question . I have checked this one , wasnt that much helpful

**UPDATE2** : Many of these tables have many relations to the other tables. but some of them wont use that much

Comment: Approach2. Don't create 100 tables unless you really have to. You could always use views if you have to simulate separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Approach1 will keep relation integrity and clean navigation properties form models.

Also your IDE will helps you completing rigth model names.

**The tip**: create and interface for all tables in order to reuse UI controls.

**Edited**

If you found a business name for this table, like `customer_data` then do a single table. If name is related with technology `master_tables` split into full semantical classes.

Answer (score 0):

100 types that inherits from Id/Title base type and EF TPH (so the DB will have 1 table with discriminator and programmers will have 100 types).

Comment: Interesting discussion about it:https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2266

Comment: Very interesting! In this case, with TPH, we pass from 2 to 3 fields (the discriminator).